# POSTGRESQL : Using previous calculated value in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good evening!
I have problem ,because I can't use MAXGROWTHPARENT value in WHERE and 
ORDER BY claused.
I wrote this query:

```
    SELECT PERSON.*, 
(
    SELECT MAX(PARENT.GROWTH) 
    FROM MAN PARENT
    WHERE 
        (PARENT.ID = PERSON.ID_FATHER)
    OR
        (PARENT.ID = PERSON.ID_MOTHER)  
) AS MAXGROWTHPARENT
FROM MAN PERSON
WHERE PERSON.GROWTH > 
(
    SELECT MAX(PARENT.GROWTH) 
    FROM MAN PARENT
    WHERE 
        (PARENT.ID = PERSON.ID_FATHER)
    OR
        (PARENT.ID = PERSON.ID_MOTHER)
)
ORDER BY (PERSON.GROWTH - 
    (
        SELECT MAX(PARENT.GROWTH) 
        FROM MAN PARENT
        WHERE 
            (PARENT.ID = PERSON.ID_FATHER)
        OR
            (PARENT.ID = PERSON.ID_MOTHER)
    )
);
```

My code looks very ugly. Can you tell me how to use MAXGROWTHPARENT
in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two separate joins might work better:

```
select p.*, greatest(pf.growth, pm.growth) as MAXGROWTHPARENT
from man p left join
     man pf
     on p.id_father = pf.id_father left join
     man pm
     on p.id_mother = pm.id_mother
order by p.growth - greatest(pf.growth, pm.growth);
```

Note:  if the joins might not match up, you might prefer:

```
select p.*, greatest(coalesce(pf.growth, pm.growth), coalesce(pm.growth, pf.growth)) as MAXGROWTHPARENT
from man p left join
     man pf
     on p.id_father = pf.id_father left join
     man pm
     on p.id_mother = pm.id_mother
order by p.growth - greatest(coalesce(pf.growth, pm.growth), coalesce(pm.growth, pf.growth));
```